# Handling jQuery + jQuery UI resources with maven

Tags: jquery, maven, jquery-ui, exec-maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

This is my current folder structure:

```
 .
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- ...
         |-- resources
         |   `-- messages
         |       `-- messages.properties
         |       `-- ...
         |   `-- properties
         |       `-- hibernate.properties
         |       `-- jawr.properties
         |       `-- ...
         |   `-- log4j.xml
         |   `-- tiles.xml
         `-- webapp
             |-- resources
             |   `-- css
             |       `-- ...
             |   `-- images
             |       `-- ...
             |   `-- js
             |       `-- main.js
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- context
             |       `-- application.xml
             |       `-- hibernate.xml
             |       `-- security.xml
             |       `-- servlet.xml
             |   `-- views
             |       `-- ...
             |   `-- redirect.jsp
             |   `-- web.xml
```

As you can see there's `js` in `src/main/webapp/resources`.
I'm using the scm plugin to check out these GitHub repositories:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

After this checkout I need to use their build machanism for concatenating and minifying and move `target/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`, `target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui.min.js`, `jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js` to `target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/js`.

Here's the necessary snippet of my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>sources</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>checkout-jquery</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>checkout</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <connectionUrl>scm:git:git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git</connectionUrl>
          <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jquery</checkoutDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>checkout-jquery-ui</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>checkout</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <connectionUrl>scm:git:git://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui.git</connectionUrl>
          <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jquery-ui</checkoutDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>make</executable>
          <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jquery</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${project.build.directory}/jquery-ui/build" />
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

I just need the following steps:

- Use `exec-maven-plugin` to use jquery's concatenating+minifying mechanism (Makefile)
- Use `maven-antrun-plugin` to use jquery-ui's concatenating+minifying mechanism (Ant build.xml)
- Move minified jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-i18n js files to `target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/js`
- then do the other lifecycle phases

But it stops on Step 2: `maven-antrun-plugin`.
To be more specific, the problem [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/build.xml#L120) on running the external shell script:

```
minify:
     [echo] Building minified
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/danny/myproject/target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/danny/myproject/target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/i18n
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/danny/myproject/target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/themes/base/minified
    [apply] build/minify-js.sh: Line 3: /home/danny/myproject/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js: File or folder not found
    [apply] Result: 1
    ...
```

The script looks on the wrong directory (`/home/danny/myproject/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js` instead of `/home/danny/myproject/target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js`)

**EDIT**: Problem is: minify-js.sh gets a wrong second argument ($2).
Adding this to modify-js.sh: `echo "test: $1 -> $2"` results in: `test: /home/danny/myproject/target/jquery-ui/build/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/jquery-ui.js -> /home/danny/myproject/dist/jquery-ui-1.9pre/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js` But why?

**EDIT2**: [I pulled a request to jquery-ui to fix this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/614)

But now I need to know how to move the minified jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-i18n js files to `target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/js` after `war:excluded`.

**What's the best way here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add another execution to your 'maven-antrun-plugin' that runs an ant 'move' command and moves everything you need.

Frankly you'll have to experiment on which phase you'll want to bind this to.  I'm guessing that war:excluded is being run during the 'package' phase.  If that's the case then, since maven doesn't have a step between package and integration tests, you can:

1. Try to bind it to 'package' and see if it runs after war:excluded
2. Bind it to pre-integration-test.  It has nothing to do with integration tests but at least you'll be confident that's running after war:excluded.